# Optimising containing for loops

Tags: python

I'm a beginner in Python and I'm trying to write a code that will go through a database of tennis games and create new columns for the number of wins of a player during his last 10 games (so for player 1 and player 2) and a third column giving the percentage of wins of player one against player 2.
I know my code works and give the result I expect, but it only works for small data and takes hours (maybe days) to compile for larger data (32,000 lines for mine).
I read that the for loops are known for taking too much time so I tried with lambdas function but I can't manage to have the right results with lambda.

Description of variables called :

```
Column 0 = Date
Column 4 = ID Player 1
Column 9 = ID Player 2
Column 19 = 1 if P1 won the game / 0 if P2 won
```

Can you help me make my code efficient even for large database ?

```
def historique(df) :
  for i in range(0, len(df)-1) :
    date = pd.to_datetime(df.iloc[i, 0])
    J1 = df.iloc[i,4]
    J2 = df.iloc[i,9]  
    #Deleting games that occured after the one studied
    df_date = df.sort_values(by='Date', ascending=False)
    df_hist = df_date.loc[df_date['Date'] < date]

    
    totv1 = 0   #Nb of wins for player 1
    totv2 = 0   #Nb of wins for player 2
    totff = 0   #% of wins for p1 over p2
    count1 = 0
    count2 = 0
    countff = 0

    #First loop to create the column equals to totv1
    for j in range(0, len(df_hist)-1) :
      if ((df_hist.iloc[j,4] == J1) & (df_hist.iloc[j,19] == 1)) | (((df_hist.iloc[j,9] == J1) & (df_hist.iloc[j,19] == 0))) == True :
        totv1 += 1
        count1 += 1
        if count1 == 10 :
          break
      elif ((df_hist.iloc[j,4] == J1) & (df_hist.iloc[j,19] == 0)) | (((df_hist.iloc[j,9] == J1) & (df_hist.iloc[j,19] == 1))) == True :
        count1 += 1
        if count1 == 10 :
          break
      else :
        count1 += 0
    df.iloc[i,8] = totv1

    #Second loop to create the column equals to totv2
    for k in range(0, len(df_hist)-1) :
      if ((df_hist.iloc[k,4] == J2) & (df_hist.iloc[k,19] == 1)) | (((df_hist.iloc[k,9] == J2) & (df_hist.iloc[k,19] == 0))) == True :
        totv2 += 1
        count2 += 1
        if count2 == 10 :
          break
      elif ((df_hist.iloc[k,4] == J2) & (df_hist.iloc[k,19] == 0)) | (((df_hist.iloc[k,9] == J2) & (df_hist.iloc[k,19] == 1))) == True :
        count2 += 1
        if count2 == 10 :
          break
      else :
        count2 += 0
    df.iloc[i,13] = totv2

    #Third loop to create the column equals tot totff
    for l in range(0, len(df_hist)-1) :
      if ((df_hist.iloc[l,4] == J1) & (df_hist.iloc[l,9] == J2) & (df_hist.iloc[l,19] == 1)) | ((df_hist.iloc[l,4] == J2) & (df_hist.iloc[l,9] == J1) & (df_hist.iloc[l,19] == 0)) == True :
        totff += 1
        countff += 1
        if countff == 10 :
          break
      elif ((df_hist.iloc[l,4] == J2) & (df_hist.iloc[l,19] == 0)) | (((df_hist.iloc[l,9] == J2) & (df_hist.iloc[l,19] == 1))) == True :
        countff += 1
        if countff == 10 :
          break
      else :
        countff += 0
    if countff != 0 :
      df.iloc[i,14] = round((totff/countff), 2)
    else :
      df.iloc[i,14] = 0

  return df
```

Comment: Looping through a DF is very inefficient for large data sets and almost never needed using Pandas because vectorized functions are available for almost every conceivable requirement. Whenever you are tempted to Loop check out better approaches.

Comment: Yes exactly but I mostly have troubles writing a problem with vectorized functions. Writing it with loops is easy and more logical in my mind and then I have trouble to transpose it with vectorized functions.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use vectorized operations in pandas instead of loops:

```
import pandas as pd

def calculate_wins(df, player_col, win_col):
    """Calculates wins for each player in the last 10 games."""
    df['win'] = (df[player_col] == df[win_col]).astype(int)
    df['cumulative_wins'] = df.groupby(player_col)['win'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(10, min_periods=1).sum())
    return df['cumulative_wins']

def calculate_head_to_head(df, player1_col, player2_col, win_col):
    """Calculates head-to-head win rate."""
    head_to_head = df.groupby([player1_col, player2_col])[win_col].agg(['sum', 'count'])
    head_to_head['win_rate'] = head_to_head['sum'] / head_to_head['count']
    return head_to_head['win_rate']

def historique_optimized(df):
    df_sorted = df.sort_values(by='Date', ascending=False)
    # Calculate wins for each player
    df_sorted['player1_wins'] = calculate_wins(df_sorted, 4, 19)
    df_sorted['player2_wins'] = calculate_wins(df_sorted, 9, 19)
    # Calculate head-to-head win rates
    df_sorted['head_to_head_win_rate'] = calculate_head_to_head(df_sorted, 4, 9, 19)
    return df_sorted

df_optimized = historique_optimized(your_dataframe)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help !
A problem I have with this formula is the fact that it doesn't take into account that for example there could be a match where Nadal is Player 1 and the next Nadal will be Player 2 but I want both to be taken into account.
I will try to use what you started I'm sure it will be very helpful !